# Regex for optional parts of string

Tags: regex, ag

How can I match all four variants shown below with one regular expression?

```
ABC
ABC_DEF
ABC_DEF_GHI
ABC_DEF_GHI_JKL
```

ABC, DEF, GHI, JKL do not represent number of characters.

I've tried something like this (only for second option) but no luck: `[A-Z]+(_[A-Z]?+)`

Comment: Split with `_`. Why do you need a regex?

Comment: I need it as part of `ag` command

Comment: If you want to match exactly 3 uppercase letters separated by `_` go with `^[A-Z]{3}(_[A-Z]{3})*$`

Comment: @Tranbi there might be many of them, cannot predict how many

Comment: @Murakami ok so replace `{3}` with `+`

Comment: @Murakami even though you haven't explained your issue or the goal you want to achieve (which should make things easier for us to either help or provide potentially better alternatives), here's a regex that should do the trick: `^[A-Z]{3}(_[A-Z]{3})*$`. You may add capturing groups as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here:
`^([A-Za-z]+)(_[A-Za-z]+)*$`

Comment: Does `*` repeat previous rule?

Comment: yes it repeats previous group from 0 to unlimited times

Comment: Great, it works, thank you also for explanation

Comment: @Murakami I edited answer first group plus was outside of group